# Cambiar estado de un AppBarToggleButton en C# (UWP)

Tags: c#, uwp

Tengo un menú creado con `AppBarToggleButton` con la propiedad `IsChecked="True"`.

¿Cómo se hace en C# para activar o desactivar su estado `"checked"`?

Comment: No hay un "Enabled" propiedad, algo semajante al: miAppBarToggleButton.Enabled = false; ? O simplemente asignar al IsChecked?

Comment: Grácias IsChecked veo que acepta (get, set) pensaba que solo era para testear si estaba checkeado o no. su uso es así IsChecked = true | false

Comment: Y no hay un "Checked" propiedad para poner "true" o "false"? (Antes fue es un error de mi cuando yo escribir "Enabled")

Comment: hay la propiedad IsEnabled pero es para definir el acceso/bloqueo del elemento

Comment: Claro que si; perso hay un simplemente llamada "Checked" (adicional a "IsChecked", que es solo como leer)?

Comment: Checked es un "evento" es decir cuando el elemento es checkedado por el usuario o por código se ejecutará lo que defines en checked, dejo la documentación oficial del elemento appbartogglebutton https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.appbartogglebutton

Comment: Ay, caramba; parece casi inconcible que no hay una propiedad para eso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo encontré, con el método `IsChecked`, además de saber si el toggle está seleccionado o no, podemos definir su estado, su uso es el siguiente

```
botonToggle.IsChecked = true;
botonToggle.IsChecked = false;
```

Pará más información referencia oficial de [AppBarToggleButton class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.appbartogglebutton)